# Disabling multi-line fields in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to disable entering multi-line entries in a Text Box (i.e., I'd like to stop my users from doing ctrl-enter to get a newline)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do it on using KeyPress event.
Here's the code example:

```
Private Sub SingleLineTextBox_ KeyPress(ByRef KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 10 _
        or KeyAscii = 13 Then
            '10 -> Ctrl-Enter. AKA ^J or ctrl-j
            '13 -> Enter.      AKA ^M or ctrl-m
        KeyAscii = 0  'clear the the KeyPress
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not by any means the best solution, because it uses the wrong event, and fires with each keystroke. The control's AfterUpdate event is much more appropriate, and fires only once.

Comment: It's working for me. No screen flicker. And in this case I want to prevent the bad input initially RATHER than try and sift it out later and either give the user an obtuse error or change their input on them.

Comment: I use this solution in combination with the [AfterUpdate solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67730/360480) because the latter one also addresses line breaks inserted via copy & paste.

Answer (score 3):

The way I did it before (and the last time I worked in Access was around '97 so my memory is not so hot) was raising a key-up event and executing a VBA function. It's a similar method to what you do with an AJAX suggest text box in a modern webform application, but as I recall it could get tripped up if your Access form has other events which tend to occur frequently such a onMouseMove over the entire form object.

Comment: Again, the KeyUp event first with each keystroke, and this can lead to flickering screen display. And it's simply inefficient -- the best event for this is still the AfterUpdate event of the control you're using to edit the memo because it fires only once.

Answer (score 3):

Using the KeyPress event means that your code will fire every time the user types. This can lead to screen flickering and other problems (the OnChange event would be the same).

It seems to me that you should use a single event to strip out the CrLf's, and the correct event would be AfterUpdate. You'd simply do this:

```
  If InStr(Me!MyMemoControl, vbCrLf) Then
     Me!MyMemoControl = Replace(Me!MyMemoControl, vbCrLf, vbNullString)
  End If
```

Note the use of the Access global constants, vbCrLf (for Chr(10) & Chr(13)) and vbNullString (for zero-length string).

Using a validation rule means that you're going to pop up an ugly error message to your user, but provide them with little in the way of tools to correct the problem. The AfterUpdate approach is much cleaner and easier for the users, seems to me.

Comment: Considering you are handling it in the front end, there's no harm in adding the Validation Rule in the database as well. It might even be a boon e.g. when a user tries to access the data via Excel, as they always do sooner or later :)

Comment: But if you put in the validation rule, you have to use the BeforeUpdate event instead of AfterUpdate. Otherwise, you'll pop the Jet data error about the validation rule violation.

Comment: I understand your argument. However, in practice I get no screen flicker with my method. Additionally, scrubbing CrLf's out after the user has made updates will change the way the data is represented from the way that they entered it. Which in turn will lead to more squawking by the users. I prefer that when they enter data, "what they see is what they get".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ian and BIBD. I created a public sub based on your answer that is reusable.

```
Public Sub PreventNewlines(ByRef KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 10 Or KeyAscii = 13 Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub

Private Sub textbox_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    Call PreventNewlines(KeyAscii)
End Sub
```

Screen flicker should never be an issue, as these are handled events, not constant polling (and it's per control further limiting the scope). Seems to me like an invalid argument, as every text editor is executing some code per keystroke.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

not entirely sure about that one, you should be able to remove the line breaks when you render the content though, or even run a vbscript to clear it out, you just need to check for chr(13) or vbCrLf.

Comment: Not quite what I wanted. It means that I'm having to monkey with the user's data in the background (not WYSIWYG) or be throwing errors that I would have put a lot of explanation behind. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an event interfering, you can set up the Validation Rule property for the textbox to be

```
NOT LIKE "*"+Chr(10)+"*" OR "*"+Chr(13)+"*"
```

You will probably also want to set the Validation Text to explain specifically why Access is throwing up an error box.

Comment: Not quite what I wanted either, user never seem to understand the validation text. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Jason's response works well. Just to add to it..

If you want to allow the user to leave the text box blank, you could use this:

Not Like "*"+Chr(10)+"*" Or "*"+Chr(13)+"*" Or Is Null